# can I show a dialog / popup when clicking a button inside fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, button, popup

I have a problem when it will display a custom dialog, I mean the button that is in the fragment when I click will popup / dialog.
anyone help?

Comment: Post your code so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

**Fragment**

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

public Context context;
public Activity activity;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
    //or
    this.activity = (Activity) context;
}
```

}

**Dialog**

```
public class BaseDialog extends Dialog {

public Context context;
public Activity activity;

public LayoutInflater inflater;
public Window window;
public View decorView;
private final WindowManager.LayoutParams attributes;

public BaseDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);

    activity = (Activity) context;
    this.context = context;

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    window = getWindow();
    //no title
    assert window != null;
    window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //auto dismiss dialog
    setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    //decorView
    decorView = window.getDecorView();
    attributes = getWindow().getAttributes();

}

/**
 * Transparency   0.0f - 1.0f
 *
 * @param f
 */
public void setDimAmount(float f) {
    attributes.dimAmount = f;
    getWindow().setAttributes(attributes);
}

/**
 * @param gravity gravity
 */
public void setGravity(int gravity) {
    window.setGravity(gravity);
}

/**
 * dialog animation
 *
 * @param resId
 */
public void setAnimation(int resId) {
    window.setWindowAnimations(resId);
}

/**
 * custom view
 *
 * @param view
 * @param width
 * @param height
 */
public void setContentView(View view, int width, int height) {
    super.setContentView(view);
    window.setLayout(width, height);
}
```

}

**PopupWindow**

```
public class MyPopupWindow extends PopupWindow {

public MyPopupWindow(View contentView, int width, int height) {
    super(contentView, width, height);
}

@Override
public void showAsDropDown(View anchor) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        anchor.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);
        int h = anchor.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - rect.bottom;
        setHeight(h);
    }
    super.showAsDropDown(anchor);
}

@Override
public void showAsDropDown(View anchor, int xoff, int yoff) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        anchor.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);
        int h = anchor.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels - rect.bottom;
        setHeight(h);
    }
    super.showAsDropDown(anchor, xoff, yoff);
}
```

}

**=== End ===**

```
public class MyFragment extends BaseFragment {
public void onClick(View v) {
    showDialog();
    //or
    showPup(v);
}

private void showDialog() {
    new MyDialog(context).show();
    new MyDialog(activity).show();
}

private void showPup(View v) {
    MyPopupWindow popupWindow = new MyPopupWindow(v, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
    popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.sealFragment_menu_animation);
    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view);

}
```

}